# Zend framework youtube api timeout issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube-api

Using Zend FW based Youtube api. Often getting errors on page load

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 503 <errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'><error>
```

Or

```
Read timed out after 10 second
```

Googled it and found usefull advise: set timeout to 180. But it doesn't help. Again, this error occurs **not everytime**, but **often.**

```
$yt = new Zend_Gdata_YouTube();
$yt->getHttpClient()->setConfig(array('timeout'=>180));
```

How to deal with that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 503 Service Unavailable
>
> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a
>   temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is
>   that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some
>   delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a
>   Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD
>   handle the response as it would for a 500 response.
>
> ```
>   Note: The existence of the 503 status code does not imply that a
>   server must use it when becoming overloaded. Some servers may wish
>   to simply refuse the connection.
> ```

But the real reason can be be something else,  like a configuration error.
P.S: put you`re code in a try and catch the error.